# Entity Framework Connection String Not Valid For Role Provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I've been trying to get roles working on my MVC 4.0 project.  I can query and update my database using my entity framework connection string.

```
<add name="DataContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                       provider connection string='data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                       initial catalog=Phase 2;
                       integrated security=True;
                       multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                       application name=EntityFramework'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This works fantastically.  The problem is when I try to set up my role manager it tells me I have an invalid connection string

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
         connectionStringName="DataContext" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This throws an error and tells me my connection string is wrong.  After researching apparently I have to use a separate connection string for my providers.  I have no idea how I would go about pointing two connection strings to the same context though.

This is how I currently have my Context being named.

```
public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataContext")
        {
        }
```

Is there a way to set the name dynamically or should I be looking for another way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The role provider needs to have a direct, straight ADO.NET connection string - not an EF one; the ADO.NET membership and role provider system doesn't use Entity Framework to access its tables.

So use something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="RoleProviderConnection" 
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Phase 2;integrated security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and use that straight ADO.NET connection string for your membership and role providers:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
         connectionStringName="RoleProviderConnection" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  I've tried this and I get an error somewhere along the lines of "invalid schema".  I just got work but I could give you specifics when I get home.

Comment: If I had my own roles table could I create a custom role provider to use entity framework?